# CommandInvokationFailure: Failed to re-package resources. (while using mobile ads GGDPR) unity, android

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, ads

CommandInvokationFailure: Failed to re-package resources.
D:\Androidsdk\build-tools\28.0.2\aapt.exe package --auto-add-overlay -v -f -m -J "gen" -M "AndroidManifest.xml" -S "res" -I "D:/Androidsdk\platforms\android-28\android.jar" -F bin/resources.ap_ --extra-packages com.adcolony.unitypluginpackage:com.heyzap.sdk:android.arch.core:android.arch.lifecycle.livedata.core:android.arch.lifecycle:android.arch.lifecycle.viewmodel:com.chartboost.sdk.unity:android.support.graphics.drawable.animated:android.support.v7.appcompat:android.support.customtabs:android.support.compat:android.support.coreui:android.support.coreutils:android.support.fragment:android.support.mediacompat:android.support.v4:android.support.graphics.drawable:com.google.android.gms.ads.impl:com.google.android.gms.ads_base:com.google.android.gms.ads_identifier:com.google.android.gms.ads:com.google.android.gms.base:com.google.android.gms.common:com.google.android.gms.gass:com.google.android.gms.tasks:com.gley.mobileads:com.google.android.gms:com.google.unity.ads:com.heyzap:com.fyber.inneractive.mraidkit:com.fyber.inneractive.nativekit:com.fyber.inneractive.sdk:com.fyber.inneractive.videokit:com.vungle.vungle_lib -S "E:\Client Data\project data\younesff - Mobile Ads GDPR\benten Beat em up\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\android.arch.core.runtime-1.1.0\res" -S "E:\Client Data\project data\younesff - Mobile Ads GDPR\benten Beat em up\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\android.arch.lifecycle.livedata-core-1.1.0\res" -S

Answer (score 0):

unity plugin used
https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/integration/mobile-ads-gdpr-compliant-102892

ads networks

chartboost
applovin
admob
vungle
heyzap
adcolony